# Pairs of anagrams where the two words sound and look very different

Tags: open-ended, anagram

This is a question about pairs of anagrams capable of flavoring puzzles as memorable and surprising because the two words are so different.

One of my favorite such pairs is *chesty* and *scythe*. These sound and look very different:

- two syllables; one syllable
- *c* and *h* together to represent the sound /tʃ/, with *t* representing /t/; *t* and *h* together to represent /ð/, with *c* immediately before *s* to represent /s/ (or, if you prefer, silent)
- *e* pronounced; *e* silent
- *y* pronounced two different ways
- *y* as suffix and in the root
- one pair of consecutive consonants (with that term understood as it should be, to denote a non-vocal phoneme); no pairs
- two monophthongs, no diphthong; no monophthongs, one diphthong.

The only letter pronounced the same way in both words is *s*, and even then you could reasonably say that the letter group representing the phoneme /s/ in *scythe* is *sc* rather than just *s*.

They are also a long way apart semantically.

The pair is practically a work of art!

The pair *bedroom* and *boredom* is quite good, but hardly in the same league. *Conversation* and *conservation* is at the other end of the scale.

What other pairs of very different sounding and looking words are anagrams of each other? What nice metric might we use for difference?

And what about triples or larger sets?

(I was caused to think of this question after tackling [@BmyGuest's challenge question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6691). Add *r* to *toenail* and rearrange to get *relation*; *t* to *senatorial*, *alterations*; or in [@Psybin's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/7748/4234), *i* to *castle*, *elastic*.)

**Edit**
Apart from {*chesty*, *scythe*} and {*admirer*, *married*} (found by @Quark), are there any other pairs of single-word anagrams, with say five or more letters, in which no consecutive letter pair appears in both words? Four-letter examples include *part* and *trap*, too symmetric to get a high score for the difference.

Comment: This isn't intended as primarily a puzzle, more a request for help in getting to a good definition of what kind of difference (not semantic linkage) makes anagrams memorable and surprising, which of course requires lots of nice examples.

Comment: My is "Banach-Tarski" and its anagram, "Banach-Tarski Banach-Tarski".

Comment: Possibly of interest: scoring of all anagrams according to the number of pairs of non-matching consecutive letters: http://blog.plover.com/lang/anagram-scoring.html

Comment: Thanks, @MJD ! There are some excellent pairs there, including cinematographer-megachiropteran, dispensable-piebaldness,  coprophagist-topographics, masculine-calumnies, and earringed-grenadier.

Comment: sectional coastline

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not a linguist so I couldn't tell you about diphthongs or phonemes, but here are a few:

*generate* --> *teenager*

*marginal* --> *alarming*

*interests* --> *triteness*

*infringe* --> *refining*

*bargained* --> *gabardine*

EDIT:

Here's a good one I found:

*altering* --> *relating* --> *alerting* --> *triangle* --> *integral*

Comment: These are all pretty nice, but in each pair except the last the two words share a vowel sound (which can be either the first or second in _interests_ - assuming you pronounce it as a trisyllable - depending on how you pronounce _triteness_) and a string of 2-3 letters, albeit in the 3rd and 5th pairs not pronounced the same. Which takes us some way towards a possible metric.

Comment: A phoneme is a sound unit capable of bringing about a change of meaning, so for example _horse_ has 3, all different, and _lull_ has 3, the first and third counting as the same even if they are pronounced noticeably differently from each other. A monophthong is a vowel sound you can hold (try it with _cart_); a diphthong you can't hold because it's made up of two vowels, one gliding into the other (try holding the sound between the two consonants in _game_, _tone_, _now_ or _kite_.)

Comment: Note that after the question was edited this limitation would eliminate some of your examples: "in which no consecutive letter pair appears in both words". I thought of "astronomer" and "moonstarer" which only works if you accept my claim that I swapped both o's and both r's!

Answer (score 5):

Ross Eckler's *Long Well-Mixed Transposals* (Word Ways, Feb 1976, p.20) addressed this problem.  The examples in this answer are taken from Eckler's article. Here are the longest word-anagrams whose words do not have a single bigram in common. The words are 14 letters long.

nitromagnesite - regimentations (Murray Pearce, Enigma, Aug 1971)

rotundifoliate - titanofluoride

The latter was found by Dennis Ritchie in 1973. Eckler does not mention it as having been published, so perhaps Eckler's article is its first publication. Some near misses using 15-letter words:

dechlorinations - ornithoscelidan (Hercules McPherrin, Enigma, Jun 1925)

cinematographer - megachiropteran (Hercules McPherrin, Enigma, Dec 1927)

The latter two 15-letter words have the bigrams `er` and `ra` in common, but in `megachiropteran` they overlap, so you'd still need to cut each word into 14 bits if you wanted to turn one into the other by permuting the bits.

"Transposal" is Eckler's term for anagrams of one word to one word, without regard to the words' meaning, as opposed to anagrams which have some sort of semantic link, e.g. H.M.S. Pinafore $\rightarrow$ name for ship, or angered $\rightarrow$ enraged.

Answer (score 4):

**medical** and **decimal** are pretty close, but **claimed** and **declaim** are also anagrams of them.  Pick any pair.  In particular, **claimed/decimal** and **medical/declaim** both satisfy the "*no pair of letters in the same order*" criteria.

I may come up with some more later...

Answer (score 2):

Many of the anagram pairs in this hall of fame:

Dictionary = Indicatory

Elvis = Lives

Listen = Silent

Admirer = Married

Although the letters don't really have different sounds.

**Source:**

> http://wordsmith.org/anagram/hof.html

Comment: Answers that are just links aren't exactly that good, if the links break than this answer is no longer useful. Would it be too much if I asked you to add in some of the relevant information of the link in, then use the link as a reference/source?

Comment: I'll undelete my post since warspyking made the effort to edit it with stuff from the link.

Comment: I think it is a bit *overdone* now. Can you pick a best-of with respect of the asked question (plus the link)? I think any answer that long must have a very justifiable reason. A lot of the anagrams from the site do not fit the "pairs of words" or dissimilarity property.

Comment: @Quark I was only trying to e courage you to fix it up...

Comment: Thanks for this, but the question is about anagrams of single words. I'll edit to put those pairs at the top. _Admirer_ and _married_ make a good pair - they don't share a string of 2 letters and they don't share a vowel sound if you pronounce the _a_ in _admirer_ as /ə/ ([schwa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa).) But they are (at least a lot of the time!) in the same semantic field. In fact a lot (all?) of these pairs have some semantic closeness.

Answer (score 1):

Would this pair be an interesting addition:

> ORCHESTRA and CARTHORSE

3 syllables vs 2, the C and H, and the A pronounced very differently.

But maybe they are too close in meaning - after all, they are both led by a man with a stick!