# I before E, except in the following sentences:

Tags: open-ended, wordplay, language

"[I before E](http://avko.org/free/reference/i-before-e-rule.html)" is a common mnemonic that is taught for spelling certain English words, but this mnemonic is often wrong, as pointed out in [this Language Log post](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/%7Emyl/languagelog/archives/003785.html).

The aim of this question is to create the longest grammatical English sentence with non-repeating words (each word can only be used once in the entire sentence) which contains the maximum number of words that violate the "I before E" rule, without resorting to quotations, numbers over ten, or proper nouns.

Sentences will be scored by the number of violations, minus the number of non-violations (includes words which don't include "ie" or "ei").

Example:

> Caffeinated atheists reinvent their weird foreign neighbours(7-0=**7**)
>
> Caffeinated atheists reinvent their blue foreign neighbours(6-1=**5**)

Comment: I was taught: "I before E except after C or when sounding like AY as in NEIGHBOR/NEIGHBOUR and WEIGH." That would mean that NEIGHBOUR is not a violation.

Comment: @PaulRowe There are lots of variations in the presentation of the rule, because it is such a terrible one. By some counts, there are *more* exceptions to the (unmodified) rule than there are valid examples.

Comment: Downvoters, care to explain why? I tried to model it after http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6691/growing-anagrams-what-is-the-longest-possible-list-forming-a-sentence?s=1|0.5109

Comment: I don't think that rule edit was necessary. Anything over eighty (e.g., eight thousand eight hundred eight) is covered by "non-repeating words".

Comment: @KSmarts You're right, but I'll just leave it in. I realised a few seconds after I edited it.

Comment: You need to clarify what repeating means. Does it only count if words are in a row (e.g., "very, very, very, very") or is each unique word only counted once? In the case of the latter, do repeated words that meet the rule count against you?

Comment: @EngineerToast Each word should only be used once, otherwise entries like "A B A B A B" will spoil the answers. Answers with repeats are invalid.

Comment: @MarchHo I would venture a guess that this is downvoted because the answers are all going to be either ridiculous sentences that no human would ever use and are, therefore, hecka confusing OR they're going to be snarky distortions of the rules.

Comment: @EngineerToast And whose fault is that second part?

Comment: @KSmarts Oh, I accept full blame for that. Warspyking posted the first version as a quote and I just adapted it to a sentence. I'm operating within the rules, though. I believe the words should be revised. It's really hard to do what is basically reverse code golf.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles)

Answer (score 5):

I've got 44-7=**37**

> Eighty feisty, ableit dreich, reigning sovereign sheikhs' heirs, deifing society, inveigled a weird foreign leisurely scientist's fanciest eight rottweilers to forfeit sufficient obeisance, veiling a heinous seismic gneiss vein heist, wherein they abseiled heights of neighboring ancient lithofacies, heigh-ho-ing their weighty freight with beige greige skeins, later efficiently surfeiting on stupefacient codeine.

Basically, a bunch of rich kids charmed some dogs and stole a bunch of rocks, and then OD'd on painkillers.

Answer (score 3):

### 1,752 - 5 = 1,747

With inspiration from warspyking:

> My favorite words include [abseil, abseiled, abseiling, abseils,
>   absenteeism, absenteeisms, ... , zein, zeins, zeitgeber, zeitgebers,
>   zeitgeist, and zeitgeists](http://www.morewords.com/contains/ei).

It's the entire list except for eighteen, eighteens, eightfold, eighties, and eighty due to the "no numbers over 10" rule.

I realize this is a snarky response but it's a grammatically correct sentence that meets the current requirements of the question.

The only higher scores I can think of either include numbers over 10 (a rule added to prevent other snarky responses) or are variations on the sentence that uses less words. For instance, "[List] are all words." or even "[List] are words."

Comment: It looks like the rules need to include use-mention distinction. Also, I don't think "..." is 1755 words.

Comment: @KSmarts I didn't want to type every word in the list.

Comment: That list isn't a sentence unless in quotes, which is not allowed. Also, you stole my now deleted answer :(

Comment: It's not in quotes and it doesn't need to be. I was definitely inspired by your deleted answer and I considered noting that. I'll do it now. However, yours was a quote with 0 invalid words. Mine is a sentence and, thus, must have invalid words.

Comment: @warspyking You're upset about a stolen answer? Interesting, then, that the most recent edit on your own answer makes it exactly the same as someone else's (*cough*), except for one word.

Comment: @KSmarts Nah I'm not upset, I was just noting that to make sure people new. Mine is an obvious copy as yours isn't deleted :D

Comment: Also, why not eightieth, eightieths they demonstrate 1/80, also eighties isn't a *number* over 10, it's a range. Prop you score up to 1758

Comment: I read "eightieth" as in "eightieth in line" but you're right in that it can also be fractional. Here comes the update. I'm leaving off "eighties", though, as it refers to a range of numbers that are all over 10 even though the word itself is not a number. It's the same reason I'm leaving out "eightfold". After all, we don't want to get silly here...

Comment: 1,752 - 5 = 1,757 ??? I can't believe it!

Comment: @L.F. Well, that's how New Math would have taught it. The idea is the important thing, after all.

Comment: @EngineerToast Can you recommend a good New Math good for me? XD

Answer (score -4):

I've got 45-7=**38**

> Eighty feisty, atheistic, albeit dreich, reigning sovereign sheikhs' heirs, deifing society, inveigled a weird foreign leisurely scientist's fanciest eight rottweilers to forfeit sufficient obeisance, veiling a heinous seismic gneiss vein heist, wherein they abseiled heights of neighboring ancient lithofacies, heigh-ho-ing their weighty freight with beige greige skeins, later efficiently surfeiting on stupefacient codeine.

Face it, we can go on until we hit 1767 words...

Comment: Change every "eight" to be "eighty eight"

Comment: @EngineerToast That should be spelled "eighty-eight," which is one word.

Comment: @EngineerToast or 8888888888888888888 in words. Obvious Rule Patched.

Comment: This can really go for infinity if you do it right couldn't it?

Comment: You know, kinda like "very, very, very, very"

Comment: That is pre-empted by non-repeating words though.

Comment: Does non-repeating mean you can't use a words twice in a row or does it mean you can't use it twice at all?

Comment: Also, I would argue that hyphenated words could be counted as one or two words. The official ruling would be up to OP.

Comment: @warspyking Under the loosest rules, it could. If you count hyphenated words as 2 words and allow repeated words so long as they aren't in a row, you could use "eighty-eight trillion, eighty-eight billion, eighty-eight million, ..." and gain 1 net point (2-1) on every instance. 888 counts the same as 88, though, so you may as well write 88,088,088,088,...

Comment: Why did you copy the answer though? It appears that it is clearly made in bad faith.

Comment: @March Ho It's 1 more point, it was made simply to demonstrate that you can really just keep on going. Eventually we'd hit a max of 2767, it'd take too long to do do however. No bad faith here. :)