# 9 letter word decomposition

Tags: english, wordplay

Give a 9 letter English word, which remains a word even after you keep removing a letter from it at each step until you have just one letter remaining.

Give the letter you remove and the word at each step.

An example of a 3 letter word would be:

**Pig**

Remove **g** - **pi**

Remove **p** - **i**

**NOTE**:

- You cannot shuffle the letters around
- The words cannot be proper nouns. None of them.
- The words have to be proper English words. No slangs, no informal words.

Comment: @mdc32: it's not because you cannot shuffle the letters around.

Comment: @pacoverflow: it's not because most words they used there are not proper or actual words and here you cannot use proper nouns.

Comment: I can understand mine, but this is definitely a dupe of the question pacoverflow linked. Kevin's solution with "complecting" uses no proper nouns - they aren't common by any means, but they're still real words.

Comment: @mdc32: "ope" is a word but not "oping". "comping" is an informal word, used by musicians and such but definitely not formal english word.

Comment: @DippedBits - Doesn't this [9-letter word](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/6696/5188) meet all of your conditions?

Comment: Nice. It Does. +1