# Build words starting with one letter

Tags: wordplay, letters

Start with a one letter word. Then add one letter (anywhere) at a time to create another word. (So the second word will be 2 letters, third word woulld be 3 letters and so on). Get to at least 7 letters. My final word is something I don't want to happen to me. Two restrictions:

Only one proper noun allowed

Only 2 vowels allowed.

Hope this is not too open ended. Of course special kudos to anyone who comes up with the longest word.

Comment: Should this have the no-computers tag? It would be easy to write a program to grovel through a wordlist to find long chains; for that matter there's at least one online word-searching tool that could do it with no programming required.

Comment: You may be interested in http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6691/growing-anagrams-what-is-the-longest-possible-list-forming-a-sentence

Comment: @IanMacDonald In this case, [anagram are not allowed](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50189/build-words-starting-with-one-letter/50199#comment153709_50199)

Comment: And you cannot re arrange letters. Thanks

Comment: Okay, then http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16059/matryoshka-words

Answer (score 8):

Here's a 10 letter word.

> A
>  AN
>  TAN
>  TANG
>  STANG
>  [STANGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stange) $\rightarrow$ Proper Noun
>  STRANGE
>  STRANGLE $\rightarrow$ You would not want this :-)
>  STRANGLER
>  **STRANGLERS**
>
>  I believe, you will never ever like to have them near you :-)

Comment: I don't think that you can swap the positions of existing letters as in anagram chains.

Comment: @MOehm Thanks. Came up with a better one :-)

Comment: you added S and T in one time !

Comment: @Sikorski Yup. Corrected. Thanks :-)

Comment: You could also do STRANG instead of STANGE - Gilbert Strang is the author of a popular linear algebra textbook

Answer (score 5):

Here is the longest I found so far.(9 letters)

> I
>  PI
>  PIN
>  PING
>  APING
>  GAPING
>  GASPING (Gasping for air is not a situation you want to be in!)
>  GRASPING (Wouldn't want an old pervert grasping at your stuff!!)
>  GRASPINGS

Comment: Good one stack reader. Only 1 vowel.

Comment: The word I am thinking is something I dont want to happen to me.

Comment: @DeepakMahulikar you wouldn't want an old pervert grasping your private stuff now would you? :P ... or be in a situation that you are gasping for air(drowning, yikes!)

Comment: Well since you put it that way!!!

Comment: Would "[graspings](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grasping#Noun)" count?

Comment: @Malvolio it would. I was just not sure if using plural would count or not.

Comment: @stackreader -- someone else used "Stange" -- the surname of a Norwegian fashion model.  I think a plural is fair game.

Answer (score 4):

Well, to get things started here's a 7 with no proper nouns.

> A AT HAT HATE HATER HATTER SHATTER

Comment: I'm quite sure that at least six of your seven words are proper nouns somewhere on Earth ;-)

Comment: Gareth, since shatter is a verb can you not extend it to shatters?

Comment: Of course, but then it would no longer be the case that "My final word is something I don't want to happen to me". Unless there's a disease called "the shatters" or something :-).

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by Gareth.... an 8 word.

> A AT PAT PATE PATER PATTER PLATTER SPLATTER

Answer (score 2):

> I IN BIN BING BOING BONING BONKING

I'm might be wrong, but it would be impolite to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guess (8 letters):

> I IT LIT LITE TILES SILENT LINIEST **SENILITY**

And another (7 letters):

> A AM SAM SAME NAMES AMENDS **MADNESS**

Comment: Quarkle, I apologize for unclear explanation. Cannot rearrange letters like from LIKE to TILES. Add letter without the order change. Sorry again

Answer (score 1):

Best I could do!

```
I ID AID AIDE AIDER AIDERS RAIDERS BRAIDERS ABRAIDERS
```

Comment: "*My final word is something I don't want to happen to me.*"?

Comment: 3 vowels were used also

Answer (score 0):

No proper nouns, only adding to end/beginning:

> a as ass pass passé passel passels

Comment: Missed the rule about not happening to you :\

Answer (score 0):

> A
>  Al
>  ale
>  sale
>  scale
>  scaled
>  scalded
>  Don't want to get scalded

Comment: I think AL is just a suffix.

Comment: I think that's the one allowed proper noun - Al, as in the name.

Comment: @F1Krazy Ah, yes!